# C# AutoMapper: set destination value by source value after validation in conditional mapping

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm fairly new to AutoMapper and want to know how to set a destination member to a value based on a DIFFERENT source property value and if that value is null I just want to apply the default behaviour of Automapper (keep destination value when the source is null)

```
 CreateMap<ClassA, ClassA>()                   
                    .ForMember(dest => dest.PropertyA, opt =>                             
                            opt.MapFrom(src => src.PropertyB!= null ? null : opt.UseDestinationValue())
                    )
```

This doesn't work (don't compile) the **opt.UseDestinationValue()** , what option can I use here? 
Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting a precondition for mapping destination property.

```
CreateMap<ClassA, ClassA>().ForMember(dest => dest.PropertyA, opt => opt.PreCondition((src, dest) => src.PropertyB != null));
```

This will map PropertyA only when PropertyB is not null. I did try a quick sample which gave the desired result.

Answer (score 3):

You can do as follows:

```
var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
  cfg.CreateMap<ClassA,ClassA>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.PropertyA, opt => opt.Condition(src => (src.PropertyB!= null)));
});
```

Or as follows:

```
var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
  cfg.CreateMap<ClassA,ClassA>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.PropertyA, opt => {
        opt.PreCondition(src => (src.PropertyB!=null));
        opt.MapFrom(src => src.PropertyB); // mapping process takes place here
    });
});
```

But the difference is that, the later runs sooner in the mapping process.

There is an excellent documentation in setting conditions for automapper:

https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Conditional-mapping.html

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the PreCondition option For Mapping Property

```
        CreateMap<ClassA, ClassA>()
           .ForMember(dest => dest.PropertyA, opt => {
               opt.PreCondition(src => src.PropertyB!= null);
               opt.MapFrom(src => src.PropertyB);
           });
```

Hope to help you